# Bot donot send welcome msg on its own in Direct line

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I have created a bot locally using bot framework v4 c#. It has a welcome card that automatically pops up as soon I connect my local url with emulator, but recently I deployed my bot on azure and integrated it using direct line channel in my website. Now whenever I click, it opens the bot but the welcome card does not come on its own ,it appears when I write something from my chatbot. I just want the welcome card to appaer automatically as it appears in the emulator. Guys can you help me out please? Below is the code of direct line which I am integrating in my website.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<!-- Paste line 7 to 27 after the title tag in _Layout.cshtml -->
<link href="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" 
/>
<script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js"></script>
<style>
    #mychat {
        margin: 10px;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 30px;
        left: 10px;
        z-index: 1000000;
    }

    .botIcon {
        float: left !important;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

    .userIcon {
        float: right !important;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
</style>
</head>
< body>
<!-- Paste line from 31 to 33 before the </body> tag at the end of code -->
<div id="container">
    <img id="mychat" src=""/>
</div>
</body>
```

```
<!-- Paste line 38 to 88 after the </html> tag -->
<script>
(function () {
    var div = document.createElement("div");

    var user = {
                id: "",
                name: ''
            };

    var bot = {
                id: '',
                name: 'SaathiBot'
            };

    const botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({

                secret: '',

                webSocket: false 
            })        

    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);

    div.outerHTML = "<div id='botDiv' style='width: 400px; height: 0px; margin:10px; position: 
fixed; bottom: 0; left:0; z-index: 1000;><div  id='botTitleBar' style='height: 40px; width: 400px;
```

position:fixed; cursor: pointer;'>";

```
    BotChat.App({
                botConnection: botConnection, 
                user: user,
                bot: bot 
            }, document.getElementById("botDiv"));

    document.getElementsByClassName("wc-header")[0].setAttribute("id", "chatbotheader");
    document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.target.matches = e.target.matches || e.target.msMatchesSelector;
        if (e.target.matches('#chatbotheader')) {
            var botDiv = document.querySelector('#botDiv');

            botDiv.style.height = "0px";

            document.getElementById("mychat").style.display = "block";
        };
    });

    document.getElementById("mychat").addEventListener("click", function (e) {

        document.getElementById("botDiv").style.height = '500px';

        e.target.style.display = "none";
    })
    }());
 </script>
```

Also here is my welcome card code in  c#

```
namespace Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples
{
public class WelcomeUser : SaathiDialogBot<MainDialog>
{

    protected readonly string[] _cards =
    {
        Path.Combine(".", "Resources", "WelcomeCard.json"),

    };

    public WelcomeUser(ConversationState conversationState, UserState userState, MainDialog dialog, ILogger<SaathiDialogBot<MainDialog>> logger)
        : base(conversationState, userState, dialog, logger)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await SendWelcomeMessageAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
        Random r = new Random();
        var cardAttachment = CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment(_cards[r.Next(_cards.Length)]);
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Attachment(cardAttachment), cancellationToken);
    }


    private static async Task SendWelcomeMessageAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        foreach (var member in turnContext.Activity.MembersAdded)
        {
            if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
            {

                if (DateTime.Now.Hour < 12)
                {

                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(
                        $"Hi,Good Morning {member.Name}",
                        cancellationToken: cancellationToken);

                }
                else if (DateTime.Now.Hour < 17)
                {

                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(
                        $"Hi,Good Afternoon {member.Name}",
                        cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
                }
                else
                {

                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(
                        $"Hi,Good Evening {member.Name}",
                        cancellationToken: cancellationToken);


                }
            }
        }

    }
    private static Attachment CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment(string filePath)
    {
        var adaptiveCardJson = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        var adaptiveCardAttachment = new Attachment()
        {
            ContentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
            Content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(adaptiveCardJson),
        };
        return adaptiveCardAttachment;
    }
    }
}
```

Here the saathiDialog code which inherited in welcome card. These are the two files inside my bot folder

```
namespace Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples
{
public class SaathiDialogBot<T> : ActivityHandler where T : Dialog
{
    protected readonly BotState ConversationState;
    protected readonly Dialog Dialog;
    protected readonly ILogger Logger;
    protected readonly BotState UserState;
    private DialogSet Dialogs { get; set; }

    public SaathiDialogBot(ConversationState conversationState, UserState userState, T dialog, ILogger<SaathiDialogBot<T>> logger)
    {
        ConversationState = conversationState;
        UserState = userState;
        Dialog = dialog;
        Logger = logger;
    }

    public override async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var activity = turnContext.Activity;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(activity.Text) && activity.Value != null)
        {
            activity.Text = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(activity.Value);
        }
        if (turnContext.Activity.Text == "Yes")
        {

            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"Good bye. I will be here if you need me. ", cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"Say Hi to wake me up.", cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        }
        else
        {
            await base.OnTurnAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
        }
        await ConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
        await UserState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
    }

    protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Logger.LogInformation("Running dialog with Message Activity.");
            await Dialog.RunAsync(turnContext, ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState)), cancellationToken);
        }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> If you are using WebChat or directline, the bot’s ConversationUpdate is sent when the conversation is created and the user sides’ ConversationUpdate is sent when they first send a message. When ConversationUpdate is initially sent, there isn’t enough information in the message to construct the dialog stack. The reason that this appears to work in the emulator, is that the emulator simulates a sort of pseudo DirectLine, but both conversationUpdates are resolved at the same time in the emulator, and this is not the case for how the actual service performs.

A workaround would be to send a back channel welcome event to the bot when the DirectLine connection is established and send a welcome message from the onEventAsync handler instead of onMembersAdded.

- Embedded HTML for Web Chat

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
    <style>
      #webchat {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="display: flex">
      <div style="position: relative; height: 500px; width: 500px"><div id="bot" ></div></div>
    </div>
    <script>
      (async function() {
        const res = await fetch('/directline/token', { method: 'POST' });
        const { token }  = await res.json();
        var userinfo = {
              id: 'user-id',
              name: 'user name',
              locale: 'es'
          };

        var botConnection = new window.BotChat.DirectLine({ token });

        botConnection.connectionStatus$
          .subscribe(connectionStatus => {
              switch(connectionStatus) {
                  case window.BotChat.ConnectionStatus.Online:
                    botConnection.postActivity({
                        from: { id: 'myUserId', name: 'myUserName' },
                        type: 'event',
                        name: 'webchat/join',
                        value: { locale: 'en-US' }
                    }).subscribe(
                        id => console.log("Posted welcome event, assigned ID ", id),
                        error => console.log("Error posting activity", error)
                    );
                    break;
              }
          });


        BotChat.App({
          botConnection: botConnection,
          user: userinfo,
          bot: { id: 'botid' },
          resize: 'detect'
        }, document.getElementById("bot"));

      })().catch(err => console.log(err));

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

- Bot Code in C#

```
protected override async Task OnEventActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IEventActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (turnContext.Activity.Name == "webchat/join") {
      await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("Welcome Message!");
    }
}

protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (turnContext.Activity.ChannelId != "webchat" && turnContext.Activity.ChannelId != "directline") {

        foreach (var member in membersAdded)
        {
            if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
            {
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"Hi there - {member.Name}. {WelcomeMessage}", cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(InfoMessage, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(PatternMessage, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Send a custom event activity.

For more information, please check this [link](https://blog.botframework.com/2018/07/12/how-to-properly-send-a-greeting-message-and-common-issues-from-customers/)